# In this first row,Explain why 'k' is printing '1' instead of '2'?

Tags: c#, loops, nested-loops

as you can see k is initially 1,im printing k++ in the console,my first output is 1 instead of 2!what's the reason behind this??

```
        var numberOfRows = 4; 
        var k = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <=numberOfRows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(k+++" ");

            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
**Output :
    1
    2 3
    4 5 6
    7 8 9 10**
```

Comment: What do you think k++ does? Reading the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/increment-operator) should clarify the behaviour.

Comment: `++k` isn't the same as `k++`

Answer (score 0):

k is evaluated as 1, THEN incremented.

Answer (score 0):

K++ is postfix operator, it will print the current value of k then increase k by 1.
If you want to increase k before printing it you should use prefix operator like ++k, it will increase k then it will print it

Answer (score 0):

k++ means 'first do whatever is called on k, then increase k by one'.

If you're looking to print k as 2, you'll need to do the opposite:
++k - 'first increase k by one, then do whatever is called on k'

Answer (score 0):

The unary increment operator `++` can appear before or after the operand (in this case, `k`).

In your example, you are using the [postfix increment operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/increment-operator#postfix-increment-operator).  The result that is printed is the value before the operation, and then the value is incremented.

To alter the behavior to first increment the value and then print, try the [prefix increment operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/increment-operator#prefix-increment-operator).

Example:

`Console.Write(++k + " ");`